# Hasura explorer disappears

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

For some reason, and after I create a custom SQL Function on `PostgreSQL` and add a `computed field` to another relation based on that function, Hasura explorer data disappears.

So, basically, I am facing this exact issue but I can see it's closed without any clear solution: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/5514

Does anyone have a workaround?